# Signing an APK with multiple certs using Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

In the development environment I'm working in, I have to double sign APKs in order for them to be installed on the phone. Is there some way I can configure Eclipse to do this double-signing before it installs the apk?

Comment: You shouldn't need to do that. Can you explain the double signing process you are doing?

Comment: I agree with Ian. I'm not sure double-signing is necessary in your case. But yes, it should be easy to do it, either through Eclipse or the command line. Keep in mind that Eclipse is just using command-line tools in the background. So you could just modify the scripts at the command-line level if you wanted, or inside the commands that Eclipse is calling, you could just add a pipe argument to allow for two arguments to be called instead of just one. In what environment are you running? Windows? Mac OS? or Linux? I'm asking because the command-line syntax will be different depending on the OS.

Comment: By the way, if the app only needs the second signature to be installed on someone else's phone, then it won't need the first signature. In other words, Eclipse already does that for you, run an apk on your phone and it will automatically sign the apk with your debug key. Export an apk for the google play store, and Eclipse will go looking for your production key to sign it with. And if you need to send an unsigned apk to someone, Eclipse can do that for you too, there is an easy way to get that unsigned apk.